# cast of (managed) Message to COPYDATASTRUCT

Tags: c++, visual-studio, managed-c++

I'm using an overriden WndProc to get an inter process communication done, according to this example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-data-copy
I have no problem with the sender, this works fine. However, as soon as I want to get the content of the LParam, I cannot get it compiled and I simply don't understand what is causing the problem.

```
protected:
    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction::Demand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag::UnmanagedCode)]
    virtual void WndProc(Message %m) override

    {
        PCOPYDATASTRUCT pMyCDS;
        // Listen for operating system messages.
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
        case WM_COPYDATA:
            pMyCDS = (PCOPYDATASTRUCT)m.lParam; //doesn't work: Failure: E0413  no suitable conversion function from "System::IntPtr" to "PCOPYDATASTRUCT" exists
            break;
        }
    }
```

If I simply do some other stuff inside the WM_COPYDATA case I can confirm that the event fires, but of course I need to get to the content of lParam. How can I copy or cast the content of lParam to COPYDATASTRUCT?

I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Hmm. Managed C++ isn't my strong suit and maybe you shouldn't be using 'raw' pointers. However, casting *via* a `void*` removes the error message: `pMyCDS = (PCOPYDATASTRUCT)(void*)m.lParam;`. ***Caveat Emptor***

Comment: This seems to work! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You might try this, not sure it works. I haven't done any C++/clr in a while.
But my guess is that you try to access managed memory straight from c++ without marshalling it first.

```
switch (m.Msg)
{
case WM_COPYDATA:
    auto copydata = System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::PtrToStructure<COPYDATASTRUCT>(m.LParam);
    // uses copydata here
    break;
}
```

At least I hope this will point you in a direction. :)

Comment: Oh, this is the first time I hear about Marshaling, Seems to I need to dig a little deeper. Unfortunately it doesn't compile. Error message is
C2672 'System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::PtrToStructure': no matching overloaded function found

Comment: There is two important things when mixing managed and heap memory.
Marshalling and Pinning.

Marshalling usually involves copying memory. Safe but slow. With pinning you tell the garbage collector "hey I'm busy with this reference don't clean it up until I'm done with it". 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/pin-ptr-cpp-cli?view=msvc-160

As said I am trying to refresh my memory as I type, seem c++/clr is not used by many